# Find out if a device is already signed in with Facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have added the Facebook SDK but can't find how to determine if a device is already logged in with Facebook. In that case I would like to skip the login screen.

Answer (score -1):

Refer following,this may help

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
login.loginBehavior=FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;
[login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {

    } else if (result.isCancelled) {

    } else {
        // here success login
    }
}];
```

Comment: Sorry but using this code how do i find device already logged on facebook and skip login screen??

Comment: just check session is not nil ..[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].

Comment: you need to use NSUSerdefault and check the device is already logged in or not

Comment: can you plz send me small demo or logic if possible ??

Comment: if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"firstTimeFaceBookLogin"])
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"firstTimeFaceBookLogin"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

NSLog(@"current date ===%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"firstTimeFaceBookLogin"]);